# Will stopping a charge cause a decreased life span of the battery

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

Occasionally, I need to stop battery charging, for example at 50% due to emergencies. 
Will stopping a charge cause a decreased life span of the battery?

Also, will leaving battery plugged in when I'm sleeping cause shorter life span?

I have a **Samsung-NP900X4D** laptop. ([http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-NP900X4D-A05US-15-Inch-Premium-Ultrabook/dp/B00A66XJZ6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A66XJZ6))

**Why I ask?**

In http://www.wired.com/2013/09/laptop-battery/, see what's recommended and the top comment with 40 upvotes. They are exactly opposite. So what should we do in this case, or what to follow?

Note that I don't know anything about AC, battery type or those sort of things, I'm not an advanced user.

Comment: The kind of battery affects the answer. e.g., Li-Ion vs NiMH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just shouldn't care. Just charge the battery whenever it's convenient so that you will have a good charge when you need it. Trying to adjust your behavior to maximize the battery's life just isn't worth the inconvenience. Do you really, really care if the battery lasts 3.9 years or 4.1 years?

Leaving the battery plugged in when you're sleeping won't cause a shorter life span. With the charger unplugged, the laptop's battery manager has no choice. With the charger plugged in, the laptop's battery manager can make the best decisions to prolong your battery's life, perhaps charging it, perhaps floating it. Giving the charger more choices will enable it to make better decisions that prolong your battery's life.

And even if it does reduce the battery's life by a tiny percentage (which it doesn't), do you really want to wake up to a dead or weak battery? What if you need to travel with the laptop? Do you really want to arrange your use of the laptop around microscopic affects on battery life?

Answer (score 1):

This has no "noticeable" effect on battery life. A battery at 50% and then being unplugged, is the same as a battery unplugged at 100% but currently at 50% due to use. In theory it has the exact same effect on the charge either way. A battery at 50% is a battery at 50%. The only thing that really "helps" battery life that I have found is to keep it plugged in and not let it use it's charge, as often as possible. From my experience over many laptops this seems to be true.

Also just food for thought going with that article. Whats the difference between never letting a battery  go over 80% and a good battery that after years of use finally wears down to only 80%? Even if you got a few more uses because of never going over 80%, "battery hours" would still probably be close to the same since you get more "hours" out of a 100% battery.